# Is there any thing just like Bundle in C#?

Tags: c#, android, bundle

I'm working on a project with c# and I need something like bundle that we have on android. any suggestion?

edited:
I got the idea that bundle is not clear for everyone. It works like Dictionary but you can put almost anything (string, int, object...) in it and search for what you want based on the key.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What functionality exactly?  Are you trying to pass session state back and forth?  Are you wanting to create a dynamic object?

Comment: I'm trying to make a pack of some strings, objects and pass it to another method. on android, it is handled by bundle but I don't know how to do it on c#.

Comment: Why don't you put those values in a class you define.  What is a "bundle" buying you?

Comment: Number and names of items are not predefined and they might be changed

Comment: bundle works like a class but it has its own advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a dictionary, where you can put anything, you just have to realize that anything (with rare exceptions) in C# is `object`. So, just create `Dictionary<string, object>`.

But I would advise you you to try to come up with a better solution. One of the nice things about C# is that it's type-safe. And here you're trying to work around that, which can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

While you probably should use constructs more aligned with strongly typed language...

It looks like you need either [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) objects or `Dictionary<String, Object>` or even `Dictionary<Object, Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle is not "just passing values between methods". It's a mechanism for moving data across process boundaries. Both the method and the concept are specific to Android. To emulate it, you'd need something that implements a Map of Object *and* can be used by code running in another process, including a remote process. I can't offer any more advice, since handling this situation is beyond my knowledge.

You're always welcome to read the definition of Bundle in the open source.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but as far as I can tell you're trying to pass values from one windows form to another. If you're trying to do so, then you do this:

```
// Example objects
Object myObject;
String myString;
Form1 myForm = new Form1(myObjects, myString);
myForm.show();
```

In C#, you pass the variables across into another form just like you would for a class. You add the specific parameters in the constructor of your Form1 class and then when you want to show the Form1, you initialize the new form with the variables you want to be passed onto the form.

Comment: bundle works like a pack that you can put almost anything in it and pass to another method or class. then they are called by the key. It's something like Dictionary but in bundle you can mix anything you want and pass it.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing in C# that is like the Bundle class. You could create your own custom class which stores a list of objects. Otherwise, I think what I said in my answer is the only other way to go.

Comment: if I don't get any answer, I think I have no other choice rather than creating my own class.